# How to be redirected by an API in php?

Tags: php, api, payment

I am trying to implement payments through Chase Bank APIs (https://developer.chase.com/products/aggregation-consent/).
According to the documentation once I send a GET request I should be redirected to their website, however I tried to do the request through PHP and even if the request goes fine (Code 200) I don't get redirected to any website.

This is the php code (I tried to add some lines of code to see if I get any response, like var_dump or CURL_HEADER_SIZE):

```
<?php

include('global_variables.php');

$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'https://apidemo.chase.com/api/v1/solution/accounts-and-data-sharing/aggregator-oauth/v1/mobile/authorize?response_type=code&client-id=XYZAB12321VBF&redirect_uri=developer.chase.com&scope=aggregator&state=Union';

$header_auth = array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'playground-id-token: ' . $chToken
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_auth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($resp, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($resp, $header_size);


if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo $e;
} else {
    $decoded = json_decode($resp);

    var_dump($decoded);
}


curl_close($ch);


?>
```

I'm not expert in implementing APIs in PHP so if there is something I missed in the question just ask and I will provide it immediately.